# How to use styles in Monogame.Extended.GUI?

Tags: monogame, gui, monogame-extended

So i was looking at the [Monogame.Extended.GUI](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/tree/develop/Source/MonoGame.Extended.Gui) Project and used this [instructions](http://blog.dylanwilson.net/posts/monogame-on-dotnet-core/) to set it up in a .net Core Project. So far everythings works fine. I followed the example of the demo and created a button like this

```
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "Button1";
button.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;

var demoScreen = new Screen
{
   Content = new StackPanel
   {
        Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Centre,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Centre,
        Items = { button }
   }
};
```

Now i want to give this Button a style, for example disable any mouse interactions like hover or mouse presses. The button has a HoverStyle and a PressedStyle property but i don't know how to use it.

```
   button.Hoverstyle = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control styles are designed to be loaded from a `Skin` but you can also create them in code a bit like populating a dictionary.

```
new ControlStyle(typeof(Control)) {
    {nameof(Control.BackgroundColor), new Color(51, 51, 55)},
    {nameof(Control.BorderColor), new Color(67, 67, 70)},
    {nameof(Control.BorderThickness), 1},
    {nameof(Control.TextColor), new Color(241, 241, 241)},
    {nameof(Control.Padding), new Thickness(5)},
    {nameof(Control.DisabledStyle), new ControlStyle(typeof(Control)) {
            { nameof(Control.TextColor), new Color(78,78,80) }
        } 
    }
}
```

An example of this can be found in the [default skin implementation](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/blob/e962cec448edfeb2c40cfc6e9da4336c51bd3ca3/Source/MonoGame.Extended.Gui/Skin.cs#L121).